# Search/Examination Reports

Tags: prior-art

Does prior art encompass both:

- published applications with search report, and
- closed applications, too?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by a "closed" application. Can you clarify that?

Answer (score 1):

Anything "published" can be used as prior art if it meets the timing requirement and is not disqualified as being too far afield. It might be an issued patent, a published patent application that was abandoned before any search or examination has taken place, an article in a magazine, a web posting, an ancient sacred text, or the proverbial back of a cereal box. The definition of what is and what isn't published can be complicated.

Comment: I meant a published patent application that was disqualified because extended Search report was wrong. In fact search report did not touch the subject matter of the application that remained thus unveiled...

Comment: Anything published "is good for what it teaches" regardless of its status or treatment in a patent system.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Whose intellectual property is that then?

Comment: Who, if anyone,  has IP rights to a published document has nothing to do with its value as prior art in showing another patent claim being not new.

Comment: did not  get this last topic

Comment: I thought you asked - who has IP rights to a "closed" application. In response to that I said it is a different topic than the original post's question about what is and isn't prior art.

Comment: You are absolutely right, the questione was Who has rights to a refused applicacion

Comment: Why so you always quote "closed" applicacion

Comment: I'm primarily involved with U.S. patents and we don't have anything called a closed application so I am trying to indicate that I am not familiar with it.

Comment: Ok, the EPO called an applicacion this way prior to consider it as refused

Comment: Another question, Sir: In which way an European patent applicacion, refused, CAN be "translated" to or taken i to consideration by the US Patent Office?

Comment: This is getting off the original question but a U.S. application can be filed. If the time limit under the Paris Convention is not yet exceeded, it can get priority from the EPO filing. The treatment it got in Europe and especially the references cited need to be made available to the USPTO but they are not bound in any way by the EPO's conclusions.

Comment: Technically what is the way to do it?

Comment: Naturally, to get priority from EPO filing

Answer (score 0):

I believe the question is asking if prior art encompasses both refernces cited in the 892 and the examiner's search report.
The prior art in the search report is all the references which showed up during the examiner's search.
The prior art in the 892 is the references which the examiner considered and are part of the patent application record.